# Creating an example webpack website inside a TypeScript library results in path import errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, module

I want to add an example of how to use a library I created. I find it excruciatingly hard to do this with TypeScript and Webpack! I get some import errors that I can't fix no matter how I set this. I thought this will be easy.

CLion does not complain at all. Runnning `tsc` inside the root project directory works without errors.

Here's the exact output I get from webpack when I run `npm run dev` when my cwd is `examples/webpack` and the scripts is just `webpack`:

```
<PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\example\webpack>npm run dev

> <PROJECT-NAME>@1.0.0 dev <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\example\webpack
> webpack

Hash: 5c50eb206798faec9cc3
Version: webpack 4.41.6
Time: 2569ms
Built at: <DATE>
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = script.js
[11] ./index.tsx 9.77 KiB {0} [built]
[12] <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts 6.2 KiB {0} [built] [4 errors]
[32] ./h.ts 2.67 KiB {0} [built]
    + 30 hidden modules

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<SOME-TYPESCRIPT-FILE-WITHOUT-EXTENSION>' in '<PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src'
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts 115:14-39
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/zlib-asm/lib/Module.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '<PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\node_modules\zlib-asm\lib'
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/zlib-asm/lib/Module.js 3:110-123
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/zlib-asm/lib/BaseDeflate.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/zlib-asm/lib/Deflate.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/zlib-asm/lib/def.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/zlib-asm/browser.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/jsziptools/core/zlib_backend_wrapper.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/jsziptools/core.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/jsziptools/stream/gz/compress.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/jsziptools/stream/gz.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/jsziptools/gz/compress.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/jsziptools/gz.js
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<SOME-TYPESCRIPT-FILE-WITHOUT-EXTENSION>' in '<PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src'
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts 39:21-61
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<SOME-TYPESCRIPT-FILE-WITHOUT-EXTENSION>' in '<PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src'
 @ <PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts 40:14-43 113:14-43
 @ ./index.tsx

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts
<PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
[tsl] ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts(1,26)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '<SOME-TYPESCRIPT-FILE-WITHOUT-EXTENSION>'.

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts
<PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
[tsl] ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts(3,22)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '<SOME-TYPESCRIPT-FILE-WITHOUT-EXTENSION>'.

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts
<PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
[tsl] ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts(60,35)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '<SOME-TYPESCRIPT-FILE-WITHOUT-EXTENSION>'.

ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts
<PROJECT-PATH>/src/index.ts
[tsl] ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\src\index.ts(61,35)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '<SOME-TYPESCRIPT-FILE-WITHOUT-EXTENSION>'.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 2 hidden modules
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! <PROJECT-NAME>@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the <PROJECT-NAME>@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     <USER-PATH>.log
```

I have the following kind of structure:

```
├── examples/  
│   └── webpack/  
│       ├── index.tsx  
│       ├── h.ts
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── tsconfig.json
│       └── webpack.config.js
├── src/
    └── index.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

I need the `tsconfig.json` because I have my own implementation of the `h.ts` instead of having React.

In `example/webpack/index.tsx` I import some code:

```
import {a, b} from "../../";
```

`examples/webpack/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h",
        "allowJs":  true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable"
        ]
    }
}
```

`examples/webpack/webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.tsx',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'script.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
};
```

`/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "example"
  ]
}
```

In `package.json` I set the `main` to be `src/index.ts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix this!!! Here's what I did, not sure if all of this is required, but here we go:

First of all, I got rid of all of the *Module not found errors* by:

1. adding the `"../.."` paths in `examples/webpack/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h",
        "allowJs":  true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable"
        ]
    },
    "include": ["../.."]
}
```

2. Adding the `"../../src"` paths in `examples/webpack/webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve.modules = [
    path.join(__dirname, '../../src'), // resolves local src dependencies
    path.join(__dirname, '../../node_modules') // resolves node_modules imports 
]
```

After all this I was left with some package errors (very weird since this did not happen when running `tsc` in the root; probably something to do with webpack), namely this one:

```
ERROR in <PROJECT-PATH>/node_modules/zlib-asm/lib/Module.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '<PROJECT-PATH-WINDOWS-SLASHES>\node_modules\zlib-asm\lib'
```

I fixed the above by making the following change to `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports.node = 
    {
        fs: "empty"
    };
```

Comment: After revisiting this same question I found just the part ```module.exports.node = {fs: "empty"};``` to have been enough :D